# What is the difference between using the is-operator and using the run-time type in Dart

Tags: dart, typechecking, runtime-type

I have worked through the [dart codelab for iterables](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables) and stumbled upon this code fragment:

```
class EmailAddress {
  String address;

  EmailAddress(this.address);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
(a)          other is EmailAddress &&
(b)              runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
                 address == other.address;
....
```

What is the difference between line (a) and line (b)? For me it seems like they do the same.
Or more generally asked: What is the difference between using the is-operator and using the runtimeType property of an object for checking the run-time type in dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aSet is Iterable` – this is `true`

`aSet.runtimeType == Iterable` this is `false`

So the is check handles subclasses.

Also, we **really** recommend that you **avoid** using `runtimeType`. Especially when compiling to JavaScript. It can really blow up your compiled app size.

I'll open an issue on that codelab!

Comment: Issue opened on web page: https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/2241